# Discord Bot Python Delete User Message After Executed

Tags: python, discord.py

Can someone help me on this one, I just want to delete the message the author sent to excute the command

```py
@bot.command(description="Displays the test on_member_join message", aliases=['tw'], pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def test_welcome(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    if user.bot:
        pass
    else:
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("on %d/%m/%Y at %H:%M")
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{user.display_name} **Joined The Server**", colour=0x73D673)
        embed.set_author(name=user.display_name, icon_url=user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
        embed.add_field(name="User ID:", value=user.id)
        embed.set_footer(text=dt_string)
        #how to make it delete the message the user sent to excute this command
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=1)
```

Comment: welcome to so, what is the error, what is your desired output

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the command executing message, like `prefix test_welcome`, you can use `await ctx.message.delete()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await ctx.message.delete`, either way, i recommend you to read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).